JWT Token Not Sent with Axios in React on Deployed Server (Works on Localhost and Postman
when calling backend server api using jwt token with credentials:true in axios working good in localhost when running backend code locally but not working when deploying backend to online server its saying always no token provided but when i test in postman alwsys working good to recived data from api using jwt token but when i use in my react code not working always saying no token provided generated by middleware code why so
  const [user, setUser] = useState(null);
  console.log(user);

  useEffect(() => {
    const fetchUserData = async () => {
      try {
        const response = await axios.get(`${domain}/user`, { withCredentials: true });
        setUser(response.data);
      } catch (err) {
        console.error(err);
      }
    };

    fetchUserData();
  }, []);

i have tried to change the middleware in many ways the thing is working good in postman when i login using postman and able to access each api using jwt token and tried many possible way to send token in axios but not working

Have you tried adding the headers into the axios.get function?
useEffect(() => {
  const fetchUserData = async () => {
    try {
      const token = localStorage.getItem('jwtToken'); // or wherever you're storing the token
      const response = await axios.get(`${domain}/user`, {
        headers: {
          Authorization: `Bearer ${token}`, 
        },
        withCredentials: true,
      });
      setUser(response.data);
    } catch (err) {
      console.error(err);
    }
  };

  fetchUserData();
}, []);

Also
Have you checked the network tab and see what you are sending and if and any errors are returning to you? Check the response and the data you are sending and see if the call with the jwt is even being sent, it could be a middleware issue where you are not validating, checking if its even present, or not even including it at all. Id reccomend the first fix and seeing if adding it in the headers will work

yes i have tried these headers still i am gatting same error and even in network tab its not sending cookies but sending to same domain but not on different domain please update
